# JS forEach array slider

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wrote a function, when I click on any image inside the article, it places it in the slider.

```
Object.keys(bgImages).forEach(function(key){
                bgImages[key].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].onclick = function() {                        modal.style.display = "block";
                        modalImg.src = bgImages[key].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;
                    }
                    arrowLeft.onclick = function (){
                        modalImg.src = bgImages[key + 1].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;
                    }
              })
```

Now I need to add arrows, with the function, when I click, the next or previous picture from the collection opens

When I try to get the next image with `bgImages[key + 1].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src`, I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined`

Variable `bgImages` return HTMLCollection

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I found similar posts, but their methods do not work on my example.

Structure of `bgImages`

```
HTMLCollection(5) [figure.figure.figure--over-9000, figure.figure.figure--over-9000, figure.figure.figure--over-9000, figure.figure.figure--over-9000, figure.figure.figure--over-9000]
0: figure.figure.figure--over-9000
1: figure.figure.figure--over-9000
2: figure.figure.figure--over-9000
3: figure.figure.figure--over-9000
4: figure.figure.figure--over-9000
length: 5
__proto__: HTMLCollection
```

Structure of `bgImages[key]` : `<figure class="figure figure--over-9000"></figure>`

When I click on the arrow, I should get the NEXT item from the current collections item

UPD:

I figured out the problem (`bgImages[key + 1]` return `bgImages[01]`, but there was one more thing left: the photo switches only once

Comment: make sure you're not exceeding the `bgImages.length` when you do `key + 1`

Comment: Please share the structure of bgImages

Comment: How are you getting `bgImages`? Using `Object.keys` on an `HTMLCollection` is probably not a good way of iterating over an `HTMLCollection`...

Comment: If i use `bgImages[key.length + 1)` the next image appears. but only once

Comment: Sorry, not the next image, the third. no matter which image the arrow is pressed on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Object.keys(bgImages).forEach(function(key){
                bgImages[key].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].onclick = function() {                        modal.style.display = "block";
                        modalImg.src = bgImages[key].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;
                    }
                    let currentKey = Number(key);
                    arrowLeft.onclick = function (){
                        currentKey += 1;
                        modalImg.src = bgImages[currentKey].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bgImages[key + 1]
```

add a check like

```
var nextImg = bgImages[key + 1];
if(nextImg){
```

When your `key` is pointing to the last element then `key + 1` will result in undefined.

Comment: do a `console.log('key', key);` inside the `function(key){`  and see what is shown? Is it a number or what?

Comment: `0 "key"`;
`<figure class="figure figure--over-9000" /> "element"`;
`01 "nextkey"`;
`undefined "nextelement"`;

Comment: Now it’s clear what’s the matter, the number didn’t add up